# differentiation dependencies

Tags: maxima

I want to understand how dependencies in Maxima for differentiation work
for iterated cases.
I tried here:

```
(%i1)   depends([f],[x,y]);    
  (%o1) [f(x,y)]

(%i2)   depends([g],[x,y]);
(%o2)   [g(x,y)]

(%i3)   depends([x,y],[ε]);
(%o3)   [x(ε),y(ε)]

(%i4)   diff(g,ε);
(%o4)   (g[y])*(y[ε])+(g[x])*(x[ε])

(%i5)   h(x,y):=f(x,y)+g(x,y);
(%o5)   h(x,y):=f(x,y)+g(x,y)

(%i6)   diff(h(x,y),ε);

(%o6)   g(x,y)[ε]+f(x,y)[ε]

(%i7)   diff(h,ε);
(%o7)   0
```

In (%o4) I get the total derivative with respect to \epsilon. Whereas in (%o6)  the derivatives of x and y with respect to \epsilon are not shown. Why?
 And can I make Maxima to show these derivatives in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies declared by `depends` are only recognized for symbolic, undefined functions. The dependency is associated with the function name (a symbol).

A function with an actual definition, as defined by `:=` or `define`, is not recognized. The body of the function could contain any combination of other functions, so the only way to know on which other functions the function depends is to evaluate the function body. That is what is happening when you write `diff(h(x, y), ε)`.